# Async map ES6 + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to do asynchronous an iterator .map but I do not know how it is done correctly. I have this

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.existingLettersActions.fetchExistingLetters();        
}

render () {
var example= '';
    var x = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'asdf'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'asdf'
        }
    ]
    if (this.props.letters) {
        example = this.props.letters.map(function(item, i) {
            return (
                <tr  key={i} styleName="container">
                    <td>{item.id}</td>
                    <td>{item.name}</td>
                </tr>
            );
        });
    }
}

return (
   {example}
)
```

If I make the map over the variable 'x' works correctly and paints it correctly but if I put this.props.letters it jumps an error saying this.props.letters.map is not a function. How could I do this asynchronous?

Comment: that is very vague. What do you mean by asnychronous? Is the `letters` list filled that way, or what do you mean? Without knowing how the data gets in there, it is fairly hard to give advice

Comment: Please see [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) We can't help you on the basis of what you've provided in the question, since you haven't shown the asynchronous process that populates `this.props.letters`. The error message is also intriguing, because it tells us that `this.props.letters` **isn't** `null` or `undefined`, but it's not an array either, so...

Comment: @MarioF The data comes from an api and I want to paint the tr asynchronously. How can I make the map work asynchronously?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The data comes from an api and I want to paint the tr asynchronously. How can I make the map work asynchronously?

Comment: @jmrosdev: You can't, `map` isn't designed for asynchronous use. There are *other* things you can do, but they depend on information you haven't provided. Again: Show us what you're dealing with, and we can help. If you don't, we can't. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem (perhaps using `setTimeout` to simulate the async data population), using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @jmrosdev React does not work like that. If there is a change in the `props`, React will trigger an update automatically itself. So the question that you have to ask yourself is how to get the right data to `letters`. In order to do that, you need to trigger the request. It can be when the component is first mounted, it can be using something like `redux`. Without more details, it is impossible to tell

Comment: @MarioF 
I am using redux, I put the data of the state in the props, I get the data that I need by console (I print this.props.letters and the JSON appears to me) but the problem I have iterating the json elements ... it appears to me The message for this.props.letters.map is not a function

Comment: I would recommend you to put a sample of your work here (https://codesandbox.io/) so that it can be seen in action. That page allows to easily set up and share react+redux projects. Then it will be much clearer for us what is missing in your solution

Comment: Any solutions????

Comment: @MarioF https://gist.github.com/jmrosdev/bf668a2d5140f5105c059aaf17e8fbef

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What can I use better than the map to do this? https://gist.github.com/jmrosdev/bf668a2d5140f5105c059aaf17e8fbef

Comment: @jmrosdev: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. Again, [here's how to do a React snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @jmrosdev the `async componentDidMount` is wrong. As I said React does not work that way. That is a lifecycle method that gets called whenever React mounts a component. It is correct to trigger the fetch from there. But you are misunderstanding how `redux` works. In this case, you should dispatch an asynchronous action. When that one is finished, you should dispatch a normal action and modify the state with a reducer. Then with `connect` you can select the part of the state that you want to use. I recommend you to check a `redux` tutorial, as it seems you have some concepts mixed up.

Answer (score -1):

`console.log` is not very trustworthy, in the sence that it can show you props.letters has a value, but it may very well be that the moment your render() method was triggered this.props.letters was not yet populated with data.

It could very well be that the first time your component renders, this.props.letters will be undefined (or similar).

Because of this, it is good practise to check the prop you want to iterate over before rendering, something like:

```
render () {
    if(!this.props.letters) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    return this.props.letters.map((item) =>
        <tr  key={item.id} styleName="container__body__table__body">
            <td>{item.id}</td>
            <td>{item.name}</td>                        
        </tr>
    );
}
```

Comment: Uhmmm...I get the same error ... this.props.letters.map is not a function

Comment: Then that means whatever is in this.props.letters is NOT an array.